# Spring Boot "Error creating bean with name"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a problem with my spring boot web application.
I have MainContorller class and CheckerClass. 
It says, in the end, it is java.lang.NullPointerexception, but I am not sure what to do with that information.

MainController class:

```
package danilocongradac.webApp;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class MainController {
    private static CheckerClass checker = new CheckerClass();

    @GetMapping(value = {"/", "/home"})
    public static String mainPage() {
        return "index";
    }
    @GetMapping(value = {"/error"})
    public static String errorPage() {
        return "error";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = {"/signIn"})
    public static String inputPage() {
        return "signIn";
    }
    @GetMapping(value = {"output"})
    public static String outputPage(){
        return "output";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/inputCheck"})
    public static String inputPageCheck(HttpServletRequest req,Model m){    
        String email = req.getParameter("email");
        String password = req.getParameter("password");

        System.out.println("email: " + email);
        System.out.println("password: " + password);

        // checker
        if(checker.check(email, password)) 
            return "output";
        return "input";
    }   
}
```

And CheckerClass:

```
package danilocongradac.webApp;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CheckerClass {
    private static ArrayList<User> users;

    public CheckerClass(){
        users.add(new User("danilo", "congradac", "congradacd002@gmail.com", "danilo2002"));
    }
    public void addUser(String name, String surname, String email, String password){
        users.add(new User(name, surname, email, password));
    }
    public boolean check(String email, String password) {
        users.add(new User("danilo", "congradac", "congradacd002@gmail.com", "danilo2002"));
        for(User u : users) {
            if(email.equals(u.getEmail()) && password.equals(u.getPassword()))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And I get error message like this...
Error message is below:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mainController' defined in file [/home/danilocongradac/Documents/java/webApp/target/classes/danilocongradac/webApp/MainController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1320) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
at danilocongradac.webApp.App.main(App.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1312) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null at danilocongradac.webApp.CheckerClass.<init>(CheckerClass.java:9) [classes/:na] at danilocongradac.webApp.MainController.<clinit>(MainController.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
... 24 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `CheckerClass` class users variable is not initialized. In constructors initialise it before using it.

```
public CheckerClass(){
    users= new ArrayList<User>();
    users.add(new User("danilo", "congradac", "congradacd002@gmail.com", "danilo2002"));
}
```

Comment: happy to help. For future you should be able to understand the error messages. It clearly says that there is error in CheckerClass at line 9. That should give you some hint. Also don't afraid of long error logs. Try to look into the relavant classes throwing error